# For what values of n is K_n planar?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

For what values of n is K_n planar?

and

For what values of r and s is the complete bipartite graph $K_{r, s}$ planar?

Ok so these questions come from Tucker's: Applied Combinatorics and are in the first chapter,  so there are not many concepts I have at my disposal yet.   The two things I do kmow are that $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ are not planar and any graph that contains either of these or a configuration of them would be nonplanar as well.

This being said the only conclusion I could come up with would be any graph that is not of the form $n = 5$ or $r = 3, s = 3$. Perhaps this is true,  but I feel there is something I am. missing to get a more thorough amswer.  Hints before a solution perhaps?

Comment: HINT: For which values of $n$ does $K_n$ contain a copy of $K_5$? And is $K_n$ planar if $n<5$? Similarly, for what values of $r$ and $s$ does $K_{r,s}$ contain a copy of $K_{3,3}$? Is $K_{1,s}$ always planar? What about $K_{2,s}$?

Comment: There are a lot more than that. Can’t you find a copy of $K_5$ in $K_6$?

Comment: i forgot to mention that the one thing i though of was the values of $n$ that would contain a $K_5$ would be any graph of the form $n = 5m$ with $m\in \naturalnumbers$ and same applies for $K_{r, s}$ except $r = s = 3j$ for $j \in \naturalnumbers$  As for the second part of your question I was trying to apply the "circle-chord" method and I cannot create a circuit for any $K_{1,s}$ graph I can't create a ciruit for any $K_{2,s}$ unless $s = r$

Comment: You should be able to explain exactly how to embed any $K_{1,s}$ or $K_{2,s}$ in the plane.

Comment: hmmmm that's true.  $K_5$ would be in $K_6$ and the same idea would probably fall in place for a $K_{3,3}$ in a $K_{4,4}$ as well.  And then going to higher integers it would be the same case.......then that would mean $n \less 5$ and $r & s \less 3$.  If I were to try to prove these claims, would it involve induction?

Comment: Now you’re starting to think along the right lines.